# I cannot connect SFTP over a cellular data network

Tags: ftp, sftp, protocol, transfer

On my iPhone 11 Max Pro, I am having trouble establishing SFTP connections with the Koder app, the Files app, and the Readdle Documents app to connect to my 2021 Macbook Pro 13". The problem is that I can only connect via WiFi, not cellular internet. I receive an error message when attempting to connect with cellular data. WiFi allows for an instant connection, especially when on my own network.

The error reads "Failed to fetch directory content. Please make sure you have permission to open it and check your internet connection."

Comment: What error do you get? What type of destination is the SFTP connection to?

Comment: The error reads "Failed to fetch directory content. Please make sure you have permission to open it and check your internet connection."

Comment: I am connecting from my iPhone to my Macbook Pro, and the error only happens with cellular data connections.

Comment: Is your Macbook Pro exposed over the internet? What's the address you're trying to connect to, a public IP or private IP?

Comment: Hello, please always edit additional info such as error message (which should have been ofc included in the 1st place) into the question.

Comment: @YisroelTech I am not as tech savvy but it is the IPV4 address used for "remote login" or sharing. It is also the same address that I use to access my Administrator account on my MacBook Pro from my iPhone with no issues with WIFI.

Comment: @Destroy666 Thanks for the advice. It escaped me on my first post.

Comment: Does the IP IPv4 address by any chance start with a 192.168 (or with 10.0)?

Comment: Yes. It starts with those digits. Is that the public IP address?

Comment: No that isn't a public IP. To put things simply, you're asking the public internet to find A PRIVATE network address. This is like asking the postal service to deliver a package and giving them the address "my bedroom". Everyone has bedrooms (and every private network had private addresses, many exactly the same as yours) and that address just won't work. You need to figure out how to get communication from the public internet to your laptop, BUT that is not something to be done lightly. It is possible, but it opens your computer to all the dangers of the public internet too.

Comment: I see. I have learned something new. thank you @music2myear

Answer (score 1):

It's not just *cellular internet* on the iPhone, it would also be with any other Wi-Fi connection you connect to. Your real issue/situation is that you cannot connected to the SFTP share when you are ***not connected to the same local network as the MacBook***.

Any IP address starting with one of the following: `10.`, `172.16.`, or `192.168.` is a local/private IP address that is not something that can be reached over the internet, it can only be reached by the devices connected to the same local network (the same router.)

So, when your iPhone is on mobile data connection it tries to connect over the internet to this private IP address so it can't reach it. But when it's connected to the Wi-Fi from the same router as the MacBook is connected, then it can reach it.

In order to be able to connected remotely you would've either needed to set up a port forwarding on the router (not a very good idea, since it potentially exposed your SFTP share to the whole world) and use your public IP address (of the router the MacBook is connected to) to connect. Or you'd need a VPN running on the local network, and you connect the iPhone to the VPN which makes you as if you're on the local network so you can access the MacBook with its private IP.

Comment: Your answer is very detailed, thank you. How can I connect the iPhone to the VPN? will it provide an IP address that I should see and connect to?

Comment: Setting up a VPN isn't something very simple to do, so I can't really guide you through it here. But if you set up a VPN you'd connect your phone to the VPN using the public IP (or set-up a domain name for it with DDNS)

Comment: I appreciate you. Thanks. I bought a VPN Service and it allows for SFTP to be created through a secure network that the VPN service provides. So I Set up an SFTP connection through Koder, and now I can connect through a cellular data connection to the IP address that the VPN service provided.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Yisroel Tech and @music2myear for your answers and recommendations.

I bought a NordVPN Service and it allows for SFTP to be created through the encrypted MeshNet network. The MeshNet provides an IP address that Koder can connect to over a cellular network. So I Set up an SFTP connection with the MeshNet IP address and now I can connect through a cellular data connection to my Macbook over SFTP.  NordVPN also provides direct and unlimited file transfers, regardless of size, through a direct MeshNet connection on the mobile and desktop NordVPN apps.

1. The benefit of using an SFTP client as packaged in Koder, is that I can browse the folders in my Macbook. Koder is an offline coding app with amazing and optional connection features.
2. The benefit of using the NordVPN in-app encrypted MeshNet work, is that the file transfers are easy and one-way at a time (from iPhone to Macbook, or vice-versa), do not expose your system folders, and you can save your files anywhere you want once you access the receiving device.

This offers me more solutions than what I asked for, and beautifully what I need.

Does that also mean that I have double encryption on my traffic at once? Encryption through the MeshNet and encryption through the SFTP?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't post questions as answers. You can ask a new question and link to this one if it helps to provide context.

Comment: This is not a question posted as an answer. This is an answer. It was given to me by the users mentioned. So I posted my update, the answer. It's strange that you assumed it to be a question. It doesn't read like a question, and it is not posted like a question.